# Responsive iframe to a responsive theme

Tags: iframe

How can I make an embedded iframe to be responsive like my website theme? I have a calculator via iframe. But it doesn't follow the theme responsiveness even after I placed this CSS

iframe, object, embed{max-width: 100%;}

here is the embedded iframe code

```
<iframe style="border: currentColor; width: 375px; height: 800px; margin-top: -159px; margin-left: 410px; position: relative;" src="http://www.calculator-bmi.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-flint/js/" height="240" width="320"></iframe>
```

I hope you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe, object, embed {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 800px !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d6ufL/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but decided to contribute anyway. Making an iframe responsive both horizontally and vertically, while maintaining aspect ratio, is a bit tricky.

Your html should have a container for the iframe:

```
<div class="embed-container-noframe">
  <iframe src="http://www.calculator-bmi.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-flint/js/"></iframe>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS for making it fill the entire space available horizontally while maintaining the same aspect ratio:

```
.embed-container-noframe {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.embed-container-noframe iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can change the aspect ratio by adjusting the padding-bottom attribute of the container.

Here's a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/dWrR2/

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution >> iframe + jquery and work like a charm. jsfiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/leowebdev/6NSX3/

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
      html body {width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;font-family: arial;font-size: 10px;color: #6e6e6e;background-color: #000;} #preview-frame {width: 100%;background-color: #fff;}</style>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var calcHeight = function() {
           $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
         }

         $(document).ready(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }); 

         $(window).resize(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }).load(function() {
           calcHeight();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://yourwebsitehere.com/" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize">
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```